# Postgresql: Trigger is not working at times

Tags: postgresql, trigger, insert, row, dml

I have a PostgreSQL trigger that is not firing sometimes, even though the status is always shown as "enabled".

My trigger code is as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION audit_src_exhibit() RETURNS trigger AS $BODY$
BEGIN
  IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' then
        if new.audit_created_date is null  THEN
        new.audit_created_date := current_timestamp;
        new.audit_created_by := session_user::text;
    end if;
    else
        if new.audit_modified_date is null  THEN
        new.audit_modified_date := current_timestamp;
        new.audit_modified_by := session_user::text;
    end if;
END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END; $BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;

CREATE TRIGGER audit_src_exhibit_tr
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON <table>
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE audit_src_exhibit();
```

Is there any specific reason for this behaviour?
Does my code show any signs of known issues which would result in triggers not firing?

I am getting the audit columns as empty even though some insert and update happened today[image]

Comment: That trigger will fire for every row that is inserted or updated. What leads you to believe it doesn't fire? Please describe the symptoms in detail, ideally with example data.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe
Yes I find the column "audit_created_date " is not populated where some insert and update happened
even though trigger status is showing as "enabled"

Comment: With your code, `audit_created_date` can be NULL if the operation is an `UPDATE`.

Comment: but today all statements was insert event only no update happened

Answer (score 0):

The NULL values for `audit_created_date` could be explained if the operation was an `UPDATE`, because your trigger doesn't modify `audit_created_date` in that case.

If those were `INSERT`s, then the only possible explanations would be

1. The trigger was not defined or disabled at the time the statements happened. To preempt the follow-up question: no, PostgreSQL doesn't disable triggers on its own.
2. `session_replication_role` was set to `replica` when the statements were executed. That will prevent firing of all except replica triggers. You can change that for a trigger with

   ```
   ALTER TABLE "<table>" ENABLE ALWAYS TRIGGER audit_src_exhibit_tr;
   ```